# Approach square root

Tags: analysis

For any $a\ge 0$, let
$$
f(x)= \frac{1}{2}(x+\frac{a}{x})
$$
For any $x_0 > 0$, how to show 
$$
 \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f^n(x_0) = \sqrt a 
$$
where $f^n = f\circ f^{n-1}$.

Comment: What do you know already? This is Newton's iteration for $\sqrt{\alpha}$. If you don't have that, it will take a few steps. Start by showing that the sequence is monotone (you might have to ignore the first term) decreasing and bounded below, hence convergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See that if the limit exists then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f^n(x_0)=L\implies f(L)=L$$ so $L$ will be a fixed point of the function $f(x)=\frac12\Big(x+\frac{\alpha}x\Big)$, which we can find by solving for $x$ the following equation $$\frac12\Big(x+\frac{\alpha}x\Big)=x\\\implies x^2-\alpha=0$$

Comment: This is not a proof. The existence of the limit has to be established. David has given a correct proof and the proposer was too quick to approve a wring proof.

Comment: No this is not a proof. These are just hints. Of course one needs to establish the existence of the limit first. It is not necessary to provide full answers with all steps as long as your hint is helping the OP to solve the problem.

Comment: Fine, Abishanka. My comment is about he proposer giving a tick to the hint and not to the one who gave a complete proof.

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that $x_0,f(x_0),f(f(x_0)),\ldots$ are all positive.  When $x>0$ we have
$$\eqalign{f(x)-\sqrt a
  &=\frac12\Bigl(x+\frac ax\Bigr)-\sqrt a\cr
  &=\frac{x^2-2x\sqrt a+a}{2x}\cr
  &=\frac{(x-\sqrt a)^2}{2x}\cr}$$
which shows that in fact $f(x_0),f(f(x_0)),\ldots$ are all greater than or equal to $\sqrt a$.  Re-using and extending the previous algebra,
$$0\le f(x)-\sqrt a=\frac12(x-\sqrt a)\frac{x-\sqrt a}{x}
  \le\frac12(x-\sqrt a)\ .$$
This shows that the difference between a term of your sequence and $\sqrt a$ at any step is at most half of what it was at the previous step; so this difference tends to $0$.